# Keystone correction in Wayland

Tags: wayland

I use my computer on a projector that does not have keystone correction.  I have been using X and `xrandr --transform` to implement it:

```
       --transform a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i
              Specifies a transformation matrix to apply on the output.
```

This is notoriously buggy; in my case, putting the 4 corners at the correct position leads to a distortion starting around the diagonal.

**Question:**  Can keystone correction be done in Wayland, and if yes, how?